# getelementbyid on appended elements

Tags: javascript, audio, element

```
var track_url = data.result;

SC.get('/resolve', {
    url: track_url
}, function(track) {
    console.log(track.id);
    $('#player').append('<iframe id="soundcloud_widget"  src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/' + track.id + '&show_artwork=true&liking=true&sharing=true&auto_play=true"  width="1280"  height="720"   frameborder="no"></iframe>');
    var q = $('#player').get(0);
    console.log(q);
    var widget = SC.Widget(document.getElementById('soundcloud_widget'));
    widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function() {
        console.log("test1");
    });
    widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH, function() {
        console.log("test2");
    });
});
```

I am using this code to embed a soundcloud player dynamically on my page. Each time a new song is requested, it removes the previous play div element and reappeneds it to the HTML so you can play a new song. I have this working for the youtube API but cannot get it to work for the soundcloud. The events will not fire. I get an error on this line:

```
var widget = SC.Widget(document.getElementById('soundcloud_widget'));
```

The error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ?n=2071:211(anonymous function) ?n=2071:211(anonymous function) sdk.js:1request.onreadystatechange sdk.js:1
```

Now I believe this error is happening because when I am appending the new iframe the DOM data isnt being updated so the 'soundcloud_widget' element isnt being found by 'getelementbyid'. Unfortunately this is as far as I can get on my own.

Comment: What is the htmp you are trying insert it into?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var track_url = data.result;

SC.get('/resolve', {
    url: track_url
}, function(track) {
    console.log(track.id);
    $('#player').append('<iframe id="soundcloud_widget"  src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/' + track.id + '&show_artwork=true&liking=true&sharing=true&auto_play=true"  width="1280"  height="720"   frameborder="no"></iframe>');
    var q = $('#player').get(0);
    console.log(q);

    var element = $('#soundcloud_widget');
    var widget = SC.Widget(element);
    widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function() {
        console.log("test1");
    });
    widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH, function() {
        console.log("test2");
    });
});
```

try spit the getting of the element

> var element = $('#soundcloud_widget');

And using the element

```
var widget = SC.Widget(element);
```

this should give you the error better.

Comment: I tried that, the same error throws on var widget = SC.Widget(element); so I am still stuck. SC is definitely defined, widget is part of the library which is referenced, so the error is definitely caused by the element being appended through jquery and being fetched by getElemenyById

Comment: Updated my example, to use jquery, does the element exists on your page?

Comment: I checked the output of element and yes it returns an iframe output. So I guess the code must be in the soundcloud api but I have exhausted google searches.  This will be fun